# Shortcode for display posts on home page show only one post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, get-posts

Need to display 3 posts. I created this code:

```
add_shortcode('projects', 'projects_shortcode');
function projects_shortcode($atts, $content){

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1
    ), $atts));

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => $post_type,
    'post_status'       => $post_status,
    'posts_per_page'    => $posts_per_page
);

global $post;

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
$out = '';
if ($posts->have_posts())
    while ($posts->have_posts()):
        $posts->the_post();

        $overview_image = get_field('small_overview_image');

        $out = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '" class="project-item">                    
                <div class="project-item_img"><img class="img-fluid" src="'.$overview_image['url'].'" /></div>
                <div class="project-item_title">
                <div class="project-item_title-name">'.get_the_title().'</div> 
                <div class="project-item_title-description">'.get_the_title().'</div></div>';
        $out .='</a></div></div>';
        /* these arguments will be available from inside $content
            get_permalink()
            get_the_content()
            get_the_category_list(', ')
            get_the_title()
            and custom fields
            get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', true);
        */
    endwhile;
else
    return; // no posts found

wp_reset_query();
return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

In wp-editor use shortcode `[projects]`.

But this code displays only 1 post. `'posts_per_page' => 3` not working. I`m not php developer. Where can be an error in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
$out = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">
```

You're resetting the `$out` variable for each post. Change that to:

```
$out .= '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">
```

That will add each new post to the output of the previous post, so that when the output is returned it contains output from all posts.